# Descargar tools de SDK sin Android Studio desde Cuba

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

vivo en Cuba y desde aquí no se me permite descargar las herramientas del SDK ni por Android Studio, ni por el CMD. Entonces necesito por favor enlaces o algún lugar desde donde pueda descargar las herramientas, gracias por su atención.

Comment: Aquí no se pueden proporcionar `links` ajenos a las documentaciones oficiales. Te recomiendo **Googlear** para ver si los consigues!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Franqo